# Proper Jack Location

Tags: frame

In general, where is the best place to put a jack to prevent damage when lifting?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The jack should be placed under a frame member or on the axle.  Also, before you crawl underneath a vehicle that has been lifted by a jack, you should have an additional support in place, such as a jack stand, to protect yourself in case the jack fails.

Comment: I had a feeling about the frame, didn't know I could use the axle and didn't think about the jack stands. Thank you

Comment: I always use a block of wood beside the jack in case it fails.

Comment: Jack stands are an absolute must. Jacks slip all the time. +1 for this answer.

Comment: also, most cars have markings along the underbody showing where the jackstand should be placed.  I'm sure of the reliability of this, but my father, when a jack stand wasn't available, would use the car's tire (lying on it's side on the ground underneath the frame) as a safety precaution

Comment: Also, use the parking brake and wheel chocks if available.  (Though you may want to skip the former, if you're working on the brakes.)

Comment: And once you find out, make sure any garage you use knows where the jack goes. I had a tyre company cause damage to my car by placing the jack under a structural member, bending it just far enough to twist the steering!

Comment: @Patrick - the tyre trick is also useful when changing a tyre 'in the field'. Sling the new wheel under the car while you remove the old one, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Where the owner's manual / factory service manual say the lift points are.